# Sending JSON Data to Ext.js

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following PHP code that is capturing and encoding JSON data ready to be used by an Ext.js file:

```
<?php
$Query = "SELECT `Department`,`DepartmentHeadID` FROM `Department`";
$Result = mysql_query($Query) or die("Error 01: " . mysql_error());

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{

// Create JSON Data:
$rows[] = $r;
echo $r[0];
echo "<br />";
}
$Data = json_encode($r);

echo "<hr />";
echo $Data;
```

?>

$Data returns "false" when I echo it out by accessing the file directly.

I am then trying to capture and use this data with Ext.js and until I can resolve this "false" issue I'm a bit stuck.

No PDO being used due to the server PHP version as this is not a production environment and it's running on an internal server.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are encoding $r in JSON. 
$r is false when your loop has finished. 
Encode $rows instead ;-)

Comment: Thanks @jde

I tried that and got an error so switched a couple of things around and now I have this:

// Create JSON Data:
 $rows[] = $r;
 }
 $Data = json_encode($rows);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r(json_decode($Data));
 echo '</pre>';

Which produces this:

http://prntscr.com/7ggd2x

Now I think that's something closer to what I am looking for but hte part that's confusing me is the JSON keys, there should only be two for each row that's returned but it appears to be sending 4.

Then I need to insert this into the combo box but that's a step or three away yet I think ;)

Comment: Here's what I did:
 echo json_encode($rows);

It sends data to a JSON array OK now so I guess the missing bit is the insertion into the comboBox.